Add Custom User Property to "Show Field" section in SharePoint list
I have SharePoint 2019 on prem and in one Site Collection i have a list and i want to create two new columns with the information type "Person or Group" then choose for the first column the User Property "Cost Office" and the second "Address" from the available (Show Field) options.
The two custom properties mentioned don't appear in the (Show field) sction. In order to add them i first went to the User Profile Service in CA and changed the Policy to "Replicable", for th search settings the prpoerty is already set to "indexed". The values of the property are imported from AD.
I also made sure that the properties mentioned above have (Crawl Properties). Although these Crawl Properties are not mapped to a Managed Property, the option to "Include in full-text index" is checked which enables searching for the content of this crawled property without mapping to a managed property.
After this i ran a full Profile Sync and a full crawl of the content source of the corresponding WebApplication where the SC is, unfortunately it didn't work, the Custom User Properties "Cost Office" and "Address" still won't appear in the (Show Field) section. I'm really out of ideas, can someone pls help? Thx
